# How do I open a page when a submit button is pressed in Express?

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, submit

I'm not talking about a Button tag. I'm talking about an input tag with the type of submit. I'm using fs to load my current pages. I'm trying to learn express.

Server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/public/')));
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', function(a,b,c){
  fs.readFileSync('index.html');
});

app.post('/testaction', function(a,b){
    console.log(a.body.log);
    fs.readFileSync('public/Logged.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/testaction">
       <h1>Log This:</h1>
       <input type="text" name="log"/>
       <input type="submit", value="Press Me!"/>
     </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you share some code that would help clarify what you're trying to do? It sounds like you're trying to _send_ a particular static page back to the client in response to a particular POST request when the client submits your form.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't really need fs here.

for exemple `app.get()` takes 2 arguments : the url you want to handle and a callback with 2 or 3 arguments.

Usually we use it like this : `app.get("/",(req,res)=>{});` (req = request, and res = response).

response has a method to send file : http://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#res.sendFile

Now for your problem, you can manage this as an ajax request :

- in index.html make a POST ajax request to `/testaction`.
- in server.js just return a status in your `app.post`
- create another route like `app.get("/test",(req,res)=>{res.sendFile("public/Logged.html");});`
- in index.html redirect to `/test` if the status is ok in your ajax response.